# calling super() on child classes javascript throw Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn **ES2015 JavaScript classses**, and I started the code like this:

file: **index.js**

```
/* parent class */
class Thing {

 construct(){
    console.log("thing constructor");
 }

}

/* child class */
const Human =  class Human extends Thing {

 construct(){
   super();
 }

}


let Person = new Human();
```

file: **package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "nodemon index.js --exec babel-node"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0"
  }
}
```

by running:

`$ npm run serve`

but i got this:

```
   SyntaxError: index.js: super() outside of class constructor (14:3)
      12 | 
      13 |  construct(){
    > 14 |    super();
         |    ^
      15 |  }
```

What am I missing here?

Node version: **6.2.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are using `construct` keyword instead of `constructor`. The `super()` method can be called only from `constructor()` of a class and nowhere else. That's why you are getting the error.

Also you don't need to assign `Human` class as a `const` and can directly use it after the class declaration

```
let Person = new Human();
```

For more details on **ES6 class(es)** refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

```js
class Thing {
  constructor(){
   console.log("thing constructor");
  }
}

/* child class */
class Human extends Thing {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

let p = new Human();
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the constructor is `constructor`, not `construct`. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

For that reason, `construct` is interpreted as an ordinary method. As the error indicates, `super` can only be called inside the constructor, not in an an ordinary method.